# How do I create a module/helper to auto select the correct ruby image or video tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm using Active Storage to upload files. I would like to not have to guess which tag to use to select the active storage object based on content_type. I've created a case statement to auto select in a view that workds, but in order to practice DRY I would like to break it out into a helper or method.

Original View Code:

```
<% case @board.image.content_type
  when "image/png" %>
    <%= image_tag((@board.image.variant(resize: @board.resolution) if @board.image.attached?),  :class => "img-fluid") %>
  <% when "image/jpeg" %>
    <%= image_tag((@board.image.variant(resize: @board.resolution) if @board.image.attached?),  :class => "img-fluid") %>
  <% when "image/gif" %>
    <%= image_tag((@board.image.variant(resize: @board.resolution) if @board.image.attached?),  :class => "img-fluid") %>
  <% when "video/mp4" %>
    <%= video_tag(url_for(@board.image),controls: false, autoplay: true, muted: true, loop: true, class:"vid-fluid")  %>
  <% when "application/pdf" %>
    <%= image_tag @board.image.blob.preview(resize: "1920x1080"), :class => "img-fluid" %>
  <% when "application/msword" %>
    <%= image_tag @board.image.blob.preview(resize: @board.resolution), :class => "img-fluid" %>
  <% when "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" %>
    <%= image_tag @board.image.blob.preview(resize: @board.resolution), :class => "img-fluid" %>
  <% when "application/vnd.ms-excel" %>
    <%= image_tag @board.image.blob.preview(resize: @board.resolution), :class => "img-fluid" %>
  <% when "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" %>
    <%= image_tag @board.image.blob.preview(resize: @board.resolution), :class => "img-fluid" %>
  <% when "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" %>
    <%= image_tag @board.image.blob.preview(resize: @board.resolution), :class => "img-fluid" %>
  <% when "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" %>
    <%= image_tag @board.image.blob.preview(resize: @board.resolution), :class => "img-fluid" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', boards_path %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my attempt at creating a helper, but I have no idea how I would be able to pass the other arguments I need for the tags.

```
module BoardsHelper
  def tag_selector(content_type)

    <% case content_type
      when "image/png" %>
        <%= image_tag %>
      <% when "image/jpeg" %>
        <%= image_tag %>
      <% when "image/gif" %>
        <%= image_tag %>
      <% when "video/mp4" %>
        <%= video_tag %>
      <% when "application/pdf" %>
        <%= image_tag %>
      <% when "application/msword" %>
        <%= image_tag %>
      <% when "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" %>
        <%= image_tag %>
      <% when "application/vnd.ms-excel" %>
        <%= image_tag %>
      <% when "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" %>
        <%= image_tag %>
      <% when "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" %>
        <%= image_tag %>
      <% when "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" %>
        <%= image_tag %>
      <% else %>
        <%= image_tag %>
    <% end %>
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you not just pass the board into your helper?

```
module BoardsHelper
  def tag_selector(board, action_name)
    size = action_name == 'index' ? '300x300' : board.resolution
    case board.image.content_type
    when "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"
      image_tag((board.image.variant(resize: size) if board.image.attached?),  class: "img-fluid")
      ....
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: My show action image_tag needs to look like this ```<%= image_tag((@board.image.variant(resize: @board.resolution) if @board.image.attached?),  :class => "img-fluid") %>``` vs the index action ```<%= image_tag((board.image.variant(resize: "300x300") if board.image.attached?),  :class => "card-img-top") %>``` so you answer is only half of the solution.

Comment: Just pass the action_name to the helper and do the logic in your case statement.

Comment: To simplify things slightly you don't have to pass action_name as a parameter as it is already available in the helper.

Comment: I ended up simplifying my case statement to use string literals /image*/ and /application*/. Considering it's only for show and index action. I was overthinking the DRY, but it was good practice.